# Why is my acronym in title not expanded in HTML but in PDF?

Tags: acronyms, tex4ht

I am using the acronym package and htlatex to convert to HTML.  I discovered that using an acronym in the title does not get expanded in the HTML even if it does in the PDF.  The expansion works in regular paragraphs.  Here is my MWE to show the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\title{My Awesome \acp{AC}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % this is where the acronym should get expanded in HTML

\acresetall % reset any acronyms used to force expansion again
Expanding \acp{AC} works in regular paragraphs.

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{AC}{Acronym}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

I compile with

```
pdflatex <FILE>
pdflatex <FILE>
htlatex <FILE>
```

and get the following PDF output

[image: PDF showing title with expanded acronym]

while the generated HTML shows only the acronym (not expanded) in the title tag:

```html
...
<h2 class="titleHead">My Awesome ACs</h2>
...
<!--l. 11--><p class="indent" >   Expanding <a
 id="x1-1doc"></a>Acronyms (ACs) works in regular paragraphs.
...
```

I would like to have the HTML use the same text "Acronyms (ACs)" as the PDF instead of "ACs".

Comment: Related, but unsolved on a quick search: [First (long) occurrence of an acronym not long in title](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2012q3/000579.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference -- I did try to search for this question but hadn't seen that one.  Still interested in an answer.  Meanwhile, my current workaround is to force expansion in the title with `\acfp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `\acp` command use full acronym text only on first use. When you use it in `\title`, you are actually using it at two places - `<title>` element in the html header, title printed in the document body is the second use, which use the short form:

```html
...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title>My Awesome Acronyms (ACs)</title> 
...
</head><body>
<div class="maketitle">
<h2 class="titleHead">My Awesome ACs</h2>
...
```

I thing simplest thing you can do would be to not use acronyms in the title, but the solution which you use in your question also seems working.

Edit:

you can also provide configuration for `TITLE+` hook, which provides text for `<title>` element. This hook could be provided in the custom config file, `mycfg.cfg` for example:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{TITLE+}{My Awesome Acronyms}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

now compile your document with

```
htlatex <FILE> mycfg
```

and the acronym should be expanded in the title block correctly

Comment: As Homer Simpson would say: Doh! You were right, it is expanded in the HTML header element `<title>` and then rightfully not so in the body.  I will go with my work-around of forcing expansion with `\acfp{AC}` in the title as my actual document has a hideously long acronym there ;-)

Comment: OK :) but be aware that you should not add to `\title` all things which you can use with `pdflatex` when you are using `htlatex`. `<title>` element cannot contain any child elements, so you can run into html validation problems when you use some fancy commands there.

Comment: This might actually be a smart thing to do if it always has to be expanded in the title. If you later decide to use the `pdftitle=\@title` in `\hypersetup` in your preamble the same problem might occur in the PDF as well. @michal.h21's comment of course still holds.